# How to import this XML data into a MySQL database table?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database

I'm trying to import data (that was exported to me by an admin) from this XML file into my phpMyAdmin MySQL database table for local development purposes. Except that I don't know how to do it.

I looked into the `LOAD XML INFILE` query to load XML into one of the tables I built in my local database. However when I tried to do so either by the query

```
LOAD XML INFILE 'D://Secondary/wamp64/tmp/Part_Info.xml'
INTO TABLE dbtest.part_no
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Row>'
```

OR

```
LOAD XML INFILE 'D://Secondary/wamp64/tmp/Part_Info.xml'
INTO TABLE dbtest.part_no
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Data>'
```

the table got filled with NULL values everywhere.
I assumed this data is not in the format required by `LOAD XML INFILE` to work. (as referred from [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483207/can-i-use-mysql-load-xml-local-infile-if-my-rows-dont-have-a-name)).

How can I then import this data into my MySQL database table?

Here's the data that needs to be imported.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <Author>ANKUR PRAKASH</Author>
  <LastAuthor>Shubham Mehta</LastAuthor>
  <Created>2016-06-10T10:48:33Z</Created>
  <LastSaved>2016-06-10T16:23:58Z</LastSaved>
  <Version>16.00</Version>
 </DocumentProperties>
 <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <AllowPNG/>
 </OfficeDocumentSettings>
 <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <WindowHeight>4455</WindowHeight>
  <WindowWidth>15345</WindowWidth>
  <WindowTopX>0</WindowTopX>
  <WindowTopY>0</WindowTopY>
  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
 </ExcelWorkbook>
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s62">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="0"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s63">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s64">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Bold="1"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s65">
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"
    ss:Bold="1"/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="mltvwallinfotbl">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="12" ss:ExpandedRowCount="2001" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Column ss:StyleID="s62" ss:AutoFitWidth="0"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s63" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="92.25"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s63" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="102"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s63" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="52.5"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s63" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="180.75"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s63" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="84.75"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s63" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="35.25"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s63" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="143.25"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s63" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="67.5"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s63" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="72"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s63" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="90.75"/>
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="81.75"/>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64"><Data ss:Type="String">#</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64"><Data ss:Type="String">Part #</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64"><Data ss:Type="String">Mfr. Part #</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64"><Data ss:Type="String">Mfr. #</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64"><Data ss:Type="String">Part Description</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64"><Data ss:Type="String">Prime Part #</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64"><Data ss:Type="String">PMA</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64"><Data ss:Type="String">Key Word</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64"><Data ss:Type="String">Part Type</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64"><Data ss:Type="String">Planning Type</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64"><Data ss:Type="String">Reference Status</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s65"><Data ss:Type="String">Inventory Status</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">444-00522-700</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">444-00522-700</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">50010000</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">INDICATOR,OXYG. HIGH PRESSURE</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">444-00522-700</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">No</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="9"><Data ss:Type="String">Component</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">None</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Active</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=RANDBETWEEN(0,100)"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">444-01095-000</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">444-01095-000</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">50011658</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">BELLOWS</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">444-01095-000</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">No</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="9"><Data ss:Type="String">Expendable</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Reorder Level</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Active</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=RANDBETWEEN(0,100)"><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">444-01096-000</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">444-01096-000</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">50011658</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">UNION</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">444-01096-000</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">No</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="9"><Data ss:Type="String">Expendable</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Reorder Level</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Active</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=RANDBETWEEN(0,100)"><Data ss:Type="Number">87</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">4</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">444-01298-400</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">444-01298-400</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">50010000</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ELECTRONIC PR SENSOR MODULE</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">444-01298-400</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">No</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="9"><Data ss:Type="String">Component</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">None</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Active</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=RANDBETWEEN(0,100)"><Data ss:Type="Number">58</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">5</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">444-01298-800</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">444-01298-800</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">50011658</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">PR.SENSR</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">444-01298-400</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">No</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="9"><Data ss:Type="String">Component</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">None</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Active</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=RANDBETWEEN(0,100)"><Data ss:Type="Number">69</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">6</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">444-01300-300</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">444-01300-300</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">50011658</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">VALVE</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">444-01300-300</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">No</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="9"><Data ss:Type="String">Expendable</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">None</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Active</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=RANDBETWEEN(0,100)"><Data ss:Type="Number">22</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">7</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">443W5809JA078</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">443W5809JA078</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">50010001</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">CARPET</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">443W5809JA078</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">No</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="9"><Data ss:Type="String">Expendable</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">None</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Active</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=RANDBETWEEN(0,100)"><Data ss:Type="Number">48</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">8</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">443W5809JA079</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">443W5809JA079</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">50010001</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">CARPET</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">443W5809JA079</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">No</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="9"><Data ss:Type="String">Expendable</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">None</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Active</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=RANDBETWEEN(0,100)"><Data ss:Type="Number">98</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">9</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">443W7000-7VG</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">443W7000-7VG</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">50010001</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">KICKSTRIP</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">443W7000-7VG</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">No</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="9"><Data ss:Type="String">Expendable</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">None</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Active</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=RANDBETWEEN(0,100)"><Data ss:Type="Number">25</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">10</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">443W7000-7WD</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">443W7000-7WD</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">50010001</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">KICKSTRIP</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">443W7000-7WD</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">No</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Index="9"><Data ss:Type="String">Expendable</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">None</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Active</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:Formula="=RANDBETWEEN(0,100)"><Data ss:Type="Number">2</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <Unsynced/>
   <Print>
    <ValidPrinterInfo/>
    <PaperSizeIndex>9</PaperSizeIndex>
    <HorizontalResolution>600</HorizontalResolution>
    <VerticalResolution>600</VerticalResolution>
   </Print>
   <Selected/>
   <TopRowVisible>75</TopRowVisible>
   <LeftColumnVisible>2</LeftColumnVisible>
   <Panes>
    <Pane>
     <Number>3</Number>
     <ActiveRow>107</ActiveRow>
     <ActiveCol>4</ActiveCol>
    </Pane>
   </Panes>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
 </Worksheet>
 <ss:DocumentProperties>
   <ss:Author>Ramco Systems Ltd</ss:Author>
   <ss:LastAuthor>Ramco Systems Ltd</ss:LastAuthor>
   <ss:Created>Friday, June 10, 2016</ss:Created>
  </ss:DocumentProperties>
</Workbook>
```

NOTE: I'm not looking for a database table to specifically fit this data in. I just want to store the data in this .XML file to my local SQL database table. You are free to assume any table structure for the answer that suits you and solves the problem. However just to show my own efforts at solving it, here's the table structure I used:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `part_no`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `part_no` (
  `#` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `Part #` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Mfr. Part #` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Mfr. #` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Part Description` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Prime Part #` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PMA` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Key Word` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Part Type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Planning Type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Reference Status` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Inventory Status` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`#`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: did you check the privileges of the XML file? Also it is applicable to MySQL.Please read about it from here -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html

Comment: @Yahoo thank you for your suggestion but I'm the root user of my local development environment's databases. I'm the admin and I have complete control over the operations.

Comment: Can you post the structure of your table?

Comment: @wchiquito Hello. Kindly refer to the edits made (the NOTE).

Comment: [14.2.7 LOAD XML Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-xml.html) supports three different XML formats as mentioned in the documentation. Your XML format is some more complex, so I'm not sure what can be achieved with LOAD XML. Surely you can accomplish what you need using [13.11 XML Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/xml-functions.html), but is a little more work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider running XSLT to transform the original XML into the format MySQL requires of `LOAD XML INFILE`. Your original format has quite a bit of namespaces and other nested elements that my interfere with the MySQL upload. Like most general purpose languages, PHP comes equipped with an XSLT 1.0 processor.

One important item is to rename the database field names, specifically removing spaces, #, and periods to properly fit xml tag names (which even follows best design practices in RDBMS).

**XSLT** Script *(save as .xsl file to be referenced below)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"               
               xmlns:s="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
               exclude-result-prefixes="s">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="s:Workbook">
    <data>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="s:Worksheet/s:Table/s:Row[position() &gt; 1]"/>
    </data>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="s:Worksheet/s:Table/s:Row[position() &gt; 1]">
    <row>        
        <No><xsl:value-of select="s:Cell[1]/s:Data"/></No>
        <PartNo><xsl:value-of select="s:Cell[2]/s:Data"/></PartNo>
        <MfrPartNo><xsl:value-of select="s:Cell[3]/s:Data"/></MfrPartNo>
        <MfrNo><xsl:value-of select="s:Cell[4]/s:Data"/></MfrNo>
        <PartDescription><xsl:value-of select="s:Cell[5]/s:Data"/></PartDescription>
        <PrimePart><xsl:value-of select="s:Cell[6]/s:Data"/></PrimePart>
        <PMA><xsl:value-of select="s:Cell[7]/s:Data"/></PMA>
        <KeyWord><xsl:value-of select="s:Cell[8]/s:Data"/></KeyWord>
        <PartType><xsl:value-of select="s:Cell[9]/s:Data"/></PartType>
        <PlanningType><xsl:value-of select="s:Cell[10]/s:Data"/></PlanningType>
        <ReferenceStatus><xsl:value-of select="s:Cell[11]/s:Data"/></ReferenceStatus>
        <InventoryStatus><xsl:value-of select="s:Cell[12]/s:Data"/></InventoryStatus>
    </row>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**PHP** Script

```
// LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->load('Input.xml');

$xslfile = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xslfile->load('XSLTScript.xsl');

// TRANSFORM XML with XSLT
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xslfile); 
$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

// OUTPUT TO FILE
file_put_contents('Output.xml', $newXml);
```

**XML Output** *(use this output file to load into MySQL, again rename columns accordingly)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <row>
    <No>1</No>
    <PartNo>444-00522-700</PartNo>
    <MfrPartNo>444-00522-700</MfrPartNo>
    <MfrNo>50010000</MfrNo>
    <PartDescription>INDICATOR,OXYG. HIGH PRESSURE</PartDescription>
    <PrimePart>444-00522-700</PrimePart>
    <PMA>No</PMA>
    <KeyWord>Component</KeyWord>
    <PartType>None</PartType>
    <PlanningType>Active</PlanningType>
    <ReferenceStatus>0</ReferenceStatus>
    <InventoryStatus/>
  </row>
  <row>
    <No>2</No>
    <PartNo>444-01095-000</PartNo>
    <MfrPartNo>444-01095-000</MfrPartNo>
    <MfrNo>50011658</MfrNo>
    <PartDescription>BELLOWS</PartDescription>
    <PrimePart>444-01095-000</PrimePart>
    <PMA>No</PMA>
    <KeyWord>Expendable</KeyWord>
    <PartType>Reorder Level</PartType>
    <PlanningType>Active</PlanningType>
    <ReferenceStatus>0</ReferenceStatus>
    <InventoryStatus/>
  </row>
  <row>
    <No>3</No>
    <PartNo>444-01096-000</PartNo>
    <MfrPartNo>444-01096-000</MfrPartNo>
    <MfrNo>50011658</MfrNo>
    <PartDescription>UNION</PartDescription>
    <PrimePart>444-01096-000</PrimePart>
    <PMA>No</PMA>
    <KeyWord>Expendable</KeyWord>
    <PartType>Reorder Level</PartType>
    <PlanningType>Active</PlanningType>
    <ReferenceStatus>87</ReferenceStatus>
    <InventoryStatus/>
  </row>
...
</data>
```

Comment: Sir! You the real MVP! Thank you SO much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to run into nothing but grief trying to import Excel's XML data format. It's really only used to display in Excel. Unless someone has gone thru the trouble of mapping columns to XML fields before exporting, you're not going to get a useful file for MySQL.

The easiest solution is to open the file in Excel yourself and do a SAVE AS to CSV format.

From there the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command is powerful and easy to use - especially with well constructed CSV file.

Comment: I saved this .xml file as a .csv file. Next I followed the steps mentioned  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815741/import-csv-file-into-mysql-using-phpmyadmin) to be sure I don't screw up on my side. However when I import the data, the query runs just fine but the table ends up  having 11 rows with all fields populated with NULL values (just as when importing from the previous .xml).

I guess I just should contact the admin who provided me this dataset.

Comment: Did you save it as comma delimited or tab delimited - that example uses tabs.

Comment: Excel on my workstation provides me three types of "Save as .csv" formats to save as, namely .csv (comma delimited), .csv (Macintosh), .csv (MS-DOS). I tried two of them, namely the comma-delimited and the MS-DOS ones. Both produced the same results.

Comment: I'm just saying the example you said you used - defaults to tab separated - did you change the example to "," instead of the "\t" he uses?

Comment: To be honest when you upload a comma separated file, it automatically fills in those fields for you. When I uploaded my comma separated file it automatically filled in "Columns separated by: " field with a *,* (Ignore the asterisks). So yes I implemented the example using a comma to separate columns. I don't know about others but that's the default behaviour on my machine.